# Relations between collections in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Right now I'm working on an e-commerce app, I use Meteor 1.3.
For now I'm stucked on defining relations between two collections. I have two of them, let's say `Products` and `Customers`, I use [meteor-collection-helpers](https://github.com/dburles/meteor-collection-helpers) to manage this task and for now my code looks like this:

**Products.js**

```
import {Mongo} from 'meteor/mongo';
import {Customers} from './customers.js';

export const Products = new Mongo.Collection('products');

Products.helpers({
    getName() {
        return this.productName;
    },
    getId() {
        return this._id;
    },
    customers() {
        return Customers.findOne(this.customerId);
    }
});
```

**Customers.js**

```
import {Mongo} from 'meteor/mongo';
import {Products} from './products.js';

export const Customers = new Mongo.Collection('customers');

Customers.helpers({
    tours() {
        return Products.find({customerId: this._id});
    }
});
```

And this is the method to insert a new customer into `Customers` collection:

```
 Customers.insert({
      name,
      phone,
      email,
      productId: Products.findOne().getId(),
      product: Products.findOne().getName(),
      createdAt: new Date(),
 });
```

RIght after order form is submitted I get a new document but the problem is I can correctly apply insert method for only first document, whe I try submitting order form for the second order this document still grabs the name and id of the first document, so for now it makes no sense to use this form.
I actually changed the code a lot while googling but ended up with nothing and saved pieces I showed you because at least it works even for the only first product.
I guess I did something wrong while defining `productId` method but can't get it, so I hope to find help here. Any suggestions will be warmly welcomed and if I will find out my mistake before any posts in this topic I 'd definetely share it.

**UPD**

Solution is as easy as it can be and I didn't need package I wrote about above.
The correct query was `product: Products.findOne(this.props.product._id).productName` which made the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you found out problem by yourself but don't know the solution. `Products.findOne()` will always return you the very first document unless you pass an argument like `Products.findOne({_id :'id'})` this.

Comment: Thanks for replying!
Yep, I just can't figure it out where I take id argument from

Comment: Sorry for a delay, just visit SO to mark your answer as a correct answer